# Resolve User ID

Tags: authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

We currently have a user ID that had been issued to two different employees at two different times... neither of which overlapped.  The accounts were also created seperately in AD.  One initially, which was deleted after the employee left and then after a period of time (about a month later) a second account was created in AD using the same user ID.

The problem we're having is that when Employee #2 logs into SharePoint it identifies her as Employee#1 and we're not sure how to resolve this?

We have taken steps to delete both the MySite Pages of Employee #1 as well as deleting the user profile under the Manage Service Applications in Central Admin. Is there something we're missing?

Comment: This should probably be migrated to SharePoint.SE

Answer (score 1):

ALWAYS create users using unique IDs when working with SharePoint. If you create a new user using the exact same ID as another, SharePoint will always take the first record of the ID and use all settings referenced to this record.

If you absolutely HAVE to use the ID you're talking about, you'll have to delete the first user from the AD and delete his/hers SP userprofile/MySite.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to removing my site, Go to Site Settings of the root site, then All People, and remove the user from the site collection. This should make SP forget about that user.